# onKey and exceptions

Tags: android, validation

I'm building an Android application and I'm facing 2 problems. I'm currently using the onKey method to parse a textbox to fetch the user typed data. This is working fine but if the user choose to let the textbox blank and send the data this will cause my application to crash. I would like to add a try and catch to handle/ignore that exception and send nothing if there is a blank even if the enter key is pressed.

My second problem occur when I press the enter key. This cause to send the data 2 times and it's kinda annoying. I think it's because there is no debounce in my code and the program register a key press and a key release. I don't really know how to filter this and I may need some inputs.

Here is my code :

```
    //Listen to the "Enter" button state changes by user selection of keypad
txtSetKp.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){                                          //This method waits for the "enter" key to be hit
    public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {

        switch(arg1)
        {
              case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                   float newSetKp =  Float.parseFloat(txtSetKp.getText().toString());

                   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); //If "enter" pressed, hide keyboard
                   if(btSocket != null && btSocket.isConnected()){  
                   mConnectedThread.send("P" + newSetKp);   
                   Log.e(TAG, "P"+newSetKp);
                   }
                   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtSetPoint.getWindowToken(), 0);

                   return true;
              default: 
                   return false;

        }

       }
    });

//Listen to the "Enter" button state changes by user selection of keypad
txtSetKi.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){                                          //This method waits for the "enter" key to be hit
    public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {

        switch(arg1)
        {
              case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                  float newSetKi =  Float.parseFloat(txtSetKi.getText().toString());

                   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); //If "enter" pressed, hide keyboard
                   mConnectedThread.send("I" + newSetKi);   
                   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtSetPoint.getWindowToken(), 0);

                   return true;
              default: 
                   return false;

        }

       }
    });
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Can you post your logcat please?

Comment: Of course, I tried to post it with a copy/past but the formatting was pretty ugly is there a way to do it correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. for first problem first check whether the text is empty.

   ```
   if(txtSetKi.getText().length() != 0)
         // perform task
   ```
2. for the second problem use

   ```
   if(keyEvent == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
         // perform task
   ```

   or

   ```
      if(keyEvent == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
             // perform task
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
txtSetKp.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    txtSetKp.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {   
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    String text = txtSetKp.getText().toString();
                    if(isNullOrEmpty(text))
                        System.out.println("Empty");
                    else
                        System.out.println("Correct");
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
        public  boolean isNullOrEmpty(String value) {
            return value == null || value.length() == 0;
        }
```